# create menu in admin not working

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, menu

i tried to create menu and items under it  but nothing appeared and no errors in log

the folder structure

```
app\code\community\shopsense\shopstyle\Block
app\code\community\shopsense\shopstyle\controllers
app\code\community\shopsense\shopstyle\etc
app\code\community\shopsense\shopstyle\Helper
app\code\community\shopsense\shopstyle\Model
app\code\community\shopsense\shopstyle\sql
```

and my config.xml,path

> app\code\community\shopsense\shopstyle\etc\config.xml

```
<config>    
    <modules>
        <shopsense_shopstyle>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </shopsense_shopstyle>
    </modules>
      <global>
        <helpers>
            <shopsense_shopstyle>
                <class>Shopsense_Shopstyle_Helper</class>
            </shopsense_shopstyle>
        </helpers>
    </global>

</config>
```

and shopsense_shopstyle.xml,

> path app\etc\modules\shopsense_shopstyle.xml

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <shopsense_shopstyle>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>community</codePool>
        </shopsense_shopstyle>
    </modules>
</config>
```

> app\code\community\shopsense\shopstyle\etc\adminhtml.xml

```
<config>
    <menu>
        <shopsense  module="shopsense_shopstyle">
            <title>shopsense</title>
            <sort_order>1</sort_order>
            <children>
                 <items module="shopsense_shopstyle">
                    <title>Example</title>
                    <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                    <action>adminhtml/shopstyle/index</action>
                </items>
            </children>
        </shopsense>
    </menu>

</config>
```

and here is helper code

> path app\code\community\shopsense\shopstyle\Helper\Data.php

```
<?php
class Shopsense_Shopstyle_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract{

} 


//end of the file
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are lot of issue in this module

**issue1**:The folder names `shopsense and shopstyle should be start with upper letter`.thus means

`shopsense` be  `Shopsense`

`shopstyle` be  `Shopstyle`

**issue2:** in config.xml `shopsense_shopstyle` should be `Shopsense_Shopstyle` as your folder name

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>    
    <modules>
        <Shopsense_Shopstyle> <!- you need changer here -->
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Shopsense_Shopstyle>
    </modules>
      <global>
        <helpers>
            <Shopsense_Shopstyle> <!-- modules prefix it alwsys lowe case letter -->
                <class>Shopsense_Shopstyle_Helper</class>
            </shopsense_shopstyle>
        </helpers>
    </global>

</config>
```

**Issue3:** file `name shopsense_shopstyle.xml should be Shopsense_Shopstyle.xml` as your module class name

so need to change in this file

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Shopsense_Shopstyle> <!-- need to change here -->
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>community</codePool>
        </Shopsense_Shopstyle>
    </modules>
</config> <!-- need to change here -->
```

**Issue4:** `all xml file  should be` start  with `<?xml version="1.0" ?>`

Comment: thanks thats helped me 
please tell  good tutorial to learn from it as the magento Documentation is hell

Comment: This is the best intro I've found https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLrbYkjuliSBKd9Nf10Pt4Ii_kwWyq-Oxc